# Sum of a sequence in Python

Tags: python, math, lambda

Let me present my problem in mathematical notation before diving into the programming aspect.

Let `a_n` be the sequence whose `i`th term is defined as `i^2 - (i-1)^2`. It is easy to see `a_i = 2i-1`. Hence (in mathematical notation) we have `a_n = {2-1, 4-1, ..., 2n-1} = {1, 3, 5, ..., 2n -1}`, the sequence of all odd integers in the range `[1, 2n]`.

In HacerRank, an excercise is to define a function that computes the sum `S_n = a_1 + a_2 + ... + a_n` and then finds `x` in the equation `S_n = x (mod 10^9 + 7)` (still using math notation). So we need to find the equivalence of the sum of all odd integers up to `2n` in `mod 10^9 + 7`.

Now, to go into the programming aspect, here's what I attempted:

```
def summingSeries(n):
    # Firstly, an anonimous function computing the ith term in the sequence.
    a_i = lambda i: 2*i - 1
    
    # Now, let us sum all elements in the list consisting of
    # every a_i for i in the range [1, n].
    s_n = sum([a_i(x) for x in range(1, n + 1)])

    # Lastly, return the required modulo.
    return s_n % (10**9 + 7)
```

This function passes *some*, but not all tests in HackerRank. However, I am oblivious as to what might be wrong with it. Any clues?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: try with n as 0,1,-1 etc

Comment: Why such a complicated way to calculate s_n? Surely it is simply `s_n = sum(range(1,2*n+1, 2))`

Comment: @user19077881 way simpler, didn't occur to me

Answer (score 1):

The solution ended being quite simple. The tests were being failed not because the logic of the code was wrong, but because it was taking too long to compute. Observing that `1 + 3 + ... + 2n-1 = n^2` we can write the function as

```
def summingSeries(n):
    return n**2 % (10**9 + 7)
```

which is clearly a major simplification. The runtime is now acceptable according to HackerRank's criteria and all tests were passed.

Comment: A bit of clarification on the derivation of the equation: `1 + 3 + ... + 2n-1= 2 + 4 + ... + 2n - n = 2 * (1 + 2 + ... + n) - n = 2 * (n * (n+1) / 2) - n = n * (n + 1) - n = n^2`

Comment: @DillonDavis: Well, given the original definition that `a_i` is `i^2 - (i-1)^2`, it's even easier than that - it's just a [telescoping sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoping_series). That is, the sum of the `a_i` from `n` down to `1` is `a_n + a_{n-1} + a_{n-2} + ... + a_1`, which by definition is `n^2 - (n-1)^2 + (n-1)^2 - (n-2)^2 + (n-2)^2 - (n-3)^2 + ... + 1^2 - 0^2`, and all the intermediate terms cancel, leaving just `n^2 - 0^2`.

Comment: A proof by induction is also straightforward.